# Codeigniter Category and Sub Categories Only Show Last Category and Sub Categories

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to show room type and rooms number inside it
example:

### room type #1

- room number 1
- room number 2
- room number 3
- room number 4

### room type #2

- room number 1
- room number 2
- room number 3
- room number 4

and so on.

this is my table

```
room_type
-------
room_type_id (int)
room_type_name (varchar)
room_price (float)
room_detail (text)

room
-------
room_e_id (int)
room_type_id (int)
room_number (int)
room_status (varchar)
```

Here's my Model

```
function get_room_type() {
    $query = $this->db->get('room_type');
    $return = array();
    foreach ($query->result() as $room) {
        $return['$room->room_type_id'] = $room;
        $return['$room->room_type_id'] -> subs = $this->get_room_list($room->room_type_id);
    } return $return;
}

public function get_room_list($room_type_id) {
    $this->db->where('room_type_id', $room_type_id);
    $query = $this->db->get('room');
    return $query->result();
}
```

And this is my Controller

```
$data['room_list'] = $this->m_fo->get_room_type();
```

And view

```
<ul>
<?php foreach ($room_list as $row) { ?>
 <li>
  <?php echo $row->room_type; ?> <?php
   if (!empty($row->subs)) {
   echo '<ul>';
   foreach ($row->subs as $sub) {
    echo '<li>' . $sub->room_no . ' - ' . $sub->room_status . '</li>';
    } echo '</ul>';
   }
  ?>
 </li> <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

but it's only show the last room type and room number in my page as you can see here -- [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9jz9.jpg)
is anything wrong or less?
Thanks You

Comment: put `var_dump($data['room_list'] )` in your controller and see it's content

Comment: here it's output https://pastebin.com/jpJQbrCS @Fast Snail

Comment: `$room->room_type_id` try changing it to `$return[$room->room_type_id]`.single quotes doesn't evaluate the value of `['$room->room_type_id']`

Comment: @FastSnail, Thank you, it works like a charm.

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the single quotes everything consider as string so you should change these two lines like this .

```
 $return[$room->room_type_id]->rooms = $room;
 $return[$room->room_type_id]->subs = $this->get_room_list($room->room_type_id);
```